# vgg16 needs less epochs than resnet ,why?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, vgg16

Recently i Have been comparing the vgg16 with resnetv1 with 20 layers.I have found out that although each epoch on vgg takes more time to complete,it generally needs less epoch to reach a certain training accuracy than resnet20.Why vgg learns faster ? is my experiments correct ? I have tried it on Cifar100 and a proportion of imagenet(tiny image net from stanford cv course)

the vgg has nearly 14m parameters but resnet has only 0.3m.
here is my implementation of the resent:

```
def resnet_layer1(inputs,initializer,
             num_filters=16,
             kernel_size=3,
             strides=1,
             activation='relu',
             conv_first=True,batch_normalization=True):


conv = Conv2D(num_filters,
              kernel_size=kernel_size,
              strides=strides,
              padding='same',
              kernel_initializer=initializer
             )

x = inputs
if conv_first:
    x = conv(x)
    if batch_normalization:
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation(activation)(x)
else:
    if batch_normalization:
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation(activation)(x)
    x = conv(x)
return x
def resnet_1(model_number,x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test,datagen,initializer,epochs=20,bs=512,output_nodes=10,optim='adam',padding='same',dout=True,callbacks=None):

depth=20
# Start model definition.
num_filters = 16
num_res_blocks = int((depth - 2) / 6)


if model_number == 1:
    resnet_layer=resnet_layer1
elif model_number == 2:
    resnet_layer=resnet_layer2
elif model_number == 3:
    resnet_layer=resnet_layer3
elif model_number == 4:
    resnet_layer=resnet_layer4

inputs = Input(shape=x_train.shape[1:])
x = resnet_layer(inputs=inputs,initializer=initializer)
# Instantiate the stack of residual units
for stack in range(3):
    for res_block in range(num_res_blocks):
        strides = 1
        if stack > 0 and res_block == 0:  # first layer but not first stack
            strides = 2  # downsample
        y = resnet_layer(inputs=x,initializer=initializer,
                         num_filters=num_filters,
                         strides=strides)
        y = resnet_layer(inputs=y,initializer=initializer,
                         num_filters=num_filters,
                         activation=None)
        if stack > 0 and res_block == 0:  # first layer but not first stack
            # linear projection residual shortcut connection to match
            # changed dims
            x = resnet_layer(inputs=x,initializer=initializer,
                             num_filters=num_filters,
                             kernel_size=1,
                             strides=strides,
                             activation=None,
                             batch_normalization=False)
        x = layers.add([x, y])
        x = Activation('relu')(x)
    num_filters *= 2

# Add classifier on top.
# v1 does not use BN after last shortcut connection-ReLU
x = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=8)(x)
y = Flatten()(x)
outputs = Dense(output_nodes,
                activation='softmax',
                kernel_initializer=initializer)(y)

# Instantiate model.
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.summary()
# Compile the model
model.compile(loss=['categorical_crossentropy'], optimizer=optim, metrics=["accuracy"])

checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=str(model_number)+'_weights.hdf5', verbose=1,save_weights_only=True,save_freq=2000000)

callbacks.append(checkpointer)

if x_test.all() == None:
    history=model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train,batch_size=bs),callbacks=callbacks,epochs=epochs, steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0]//bs)
else:
    history=model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train,batch_size=bs),callbacks=callbacks,epochs=epochs,validation_data=(x_test, y_test), steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0]//bs)

return history,model
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now more than 1 year later looking at this question, I say VGG learns faster because it has more parameters than the restnet20. The higher number of the parameters allows it to overfit to the dataset faster. More parameters allow it to be a better feature extractor. Also I mentioned it takes fewer epochs for VGG, but it does not mean overall training time is lower.

Answer (score 5):

For some reason VGG might be better suited for cifar10 (maybe kernel sizes etc.). Generally speaking, however, this isn't the case. I've trained VGGs much slower than even the largest resnets (i.e. 150 layers).

Comment: have u checked my resnet implementation? do u think it is related to that ? ofcourse when i check the number of params it is as it should be sth between 0.2-0.3m so i think it must be all right

Comment: also,all my training data is in 32x32 size can this cause resnet problems ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the resnet you're using because its pretty small, but the resnet50 (the smallest resnet I've used) required a minimum resolution of 196x196 due to its architecture. By that I mean that it didn't work with smaller images. If you trained it, your network probably doesn't have that issue

Comment: I used zero padding so that my network support the smaller resolution images as well

Answer (score 2):

I'm a pretty new to deep learning but will try to give an answer.
A short answer could be the number of features the VGG has compared to the resnet.
That being said, only relevant features are important to perform better. My guess is that the relevant features for your training are part of the VGG set and some might be absent from the resnet.

Comment: can u elaborate a bit more ? how features can be part of the vgg set ?